# Image does not align to middle

Tags: html, css, image, margin

I have a row of divs that I am trying to build a gallery row with.
Despite using align: auto; on the images, They still seem to align to the left.
I was wondering if I am missing something.

**here is my fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/82nrw19x/

here is my code:

**CSS:**

```
.galleryRow{

}

.galleryIconOuter{
    background-color: gray;
         width: 20%;
         height: 70px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}


#wrapper {
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    border: 4px gainsboro solid;
    margin: 0auto;
    position: relative;

}
#im {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
     background-image: url("https://s31.postimg.org/x8rd1797f/product1.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
    <section id="products" class="about">
    <div class="container">
            <div class="info col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2>Products</h2>
                <div class="galleryRow w3-row">
                    <div class="galleryIconOuter w3-col">
                    <div id="wrapper">
                    <div id="im">
                    </div>
                    </div>                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="galleryIconOuter w3-col">
                    <div id="wrapper">
                    <div id="im">
                    </div>
                    </div>                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="galleryIconOuter w3-col">
                    <div id="wrapper">
                    <div id="im">
                    </div>
                    </div>                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="galleryIconOuter w3-col">
                    <div id="wrapper">
                    <div id="im">
                    </div>
                    </div>                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="galleryIconOuter w3-col">
                    <div id="wrapper">
                    <div id="im">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

any help or advice is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: And where are your images? Also ids are *unique*

Comment: I have added them in the fiddle @theblindprophet

Comment: you mean, you want the images to be shown in the same row?

Comment: the images want to be centered in each box, if that makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are including the `img` as backgrounds, then you just need to set

> `background-position` to `center`:

Try this:

```
#im {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-image: url("https://s31.postimg.org/x8rd1797f/product1.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    /* ADD THIS LINE*/
    background-position:center;
}
```

Or the shorthand:

```
background: url("https://s31.postimg.org/x8rd1797f/product1.png") no-repeat center/contain;
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/82nrw19x/1/)

Comment: glad to help U @danjonescidtrix

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/82nrw19x/2/)?

```
.galleryRow{
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    left: 10%;
    right: 10%;
}
```

Is that what you mean by wanting them to "align to middle?"